# How do I print the last 4 numbers of a credit card on the templates/customers/order.liquid template?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to be able to show the card type and last 4 credit cards to a logged-in customer. But it appears that transaction objects are not available for use inside the `/templates/customers/order.liquid` template. How do I make the transaction object available inside `/templates/customers/order.liquid`?

```
card type: {{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company }}
card xxxx: {{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_number }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transaction object is part of the `order.transactions` array. (since you can have multiply transactions per a single order)

In order to output them you need to loop the array.

```
{% for transaction in order.transactions %}
  card type: {{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company }} <br/>
  card xxxx: {{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_number }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```